# Persist List of same Class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, relational-database

As someone coming from JPA to C# .Net and Entity framework, I'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around the lack of support for lists in EF.

I need to do the following:

```
public class Foo {

   public long Id {get; set;}

   //Class value objects / attributes
   //e.g
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public AnotherFoo AFoo {get; set;}

   //This class can have many children classes of the same type
   //In this case Foo can have many Foo's
   public List<Foo> {get; set;}
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to go on persisting this. I've seen articles about Hierarchical Data Management and I tried implementing them but with no success. All went fine untill I had to query the 'List' then, I would get a recursive error which I don't remember exactly what it was.

I've also searched in stackoverflow, but could not pinpoint my problem.

### TL;DR

I want to persist a class that has a list of itself in Entity Framework /.Net Core, how would I go on about it?

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could give me a hand on this! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by trying to map your type/model to a relational data table(s). How would this "look" (ie. what is the schema) in a relational database?

Comment: You are describing a Tree. You could persist it with BinaryFormatter, or as text like JSON or XML or in a database where basically it is NodeId, ParentNodeId, Value.

Comment: You tagged this with [SQLite].  It's a relational database.  Try doing this database-first (rather than code first) and you will see how EF handles one-to-many relationships represented by a foreign key.

Comment: @Flydog57 Thank you for the heads up, I changed the tag.

Comment: @Igor See comment below, I can only tag 1 person at a time

Comment: @cetin-basoz && igor thank you for your input. I'll try to implement a Tree and persist it to a relational database, let's see how that goes :)

Comment: My point wasn't about the tag, it was about the fact that it's a relational database.  1:N relationships in relational databases are generally based on Foreign Keys.  If you built a simple EF model (old school) from a pair of parent/child tables with an FK relationship, you will see the EF representation of the parent child relationship.  If I remember correctly, it involves a `DbSet<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that you don't describe your schema to Entity Framework, i.e you don't define the relationships between you objects.

Here is a suggestion that works:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AFoo")]
    public int? AFooID { get; set; }
    public virtual AnotherFoo AFoo { get; set; }

    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Foo> Children { get; set; } = new List<Foo>();
}

public class AnotherFoo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Please note a couple of things:

- I have added a foreign key property `AFooID` to the AFoo entity. Entity Framework will recognize on its own the relationship between AFoo property and Foo entity and when building the schema it will also add a foreign key to AntoherFoo entity. But this key will not be available in your code because you didn't add it to the Foo class properties. Also, it is better that you have the complete control over the scema creation and don't let much to Entity Framework's imagination (which is quite good nevertheless).
- A have added an annotation `[ForeignKey("AFoo")]` over `AFooID` to define that this is a foreign key to `AFoo` navigation parameter. Normally I should also add a similar annotation over `ID` to define it as a primary key, but Entity Framework does this automatically for an integer property named `ID`.
- I have used the `virtual` keyword on all navigation parameters to allow lazy loading of those parameters.

Now, for your prime question; You can create a reference of children of the same type as if it was any other type. But you have to describe the relationship! In this example I configure an one to many relationship, meaning that each foo can have only one parent but many children. To do this I used `Fluent API`:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AnotherFoo> AFoos { get; set; }

    public MyContext()
        : base("TestDB")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
            .HasOptional(f => f.Parent)
            .WithMany(f => f.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.ParentID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Override the `OnModelCreating` method of your `DbContext` class to specify more "fluently" your database schema.

Now run the following commands in your Package Manager Console to create your database:

1. `add-migration InitialDB`
   It will create a cs file that describes the schema to be created. Check that is as you desired.
2. `update-database`
   It will create a database using the connection string defined in your config file and the schema from the file above.

Run this demo application:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo { Name = "parent foo" };
        var foo1 = new Foo { Name = "first foo child" };
        var foo2 = new Foo { Name = "second foo child" };
        foo.Children.Add(foo1);
        foo.Children.Add(foo2);

        using(var context = new MyContext())
        {
            context.Foos.Add(foo);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        // another transaction to read the saved data
        using(var context = new MyContext())
        {
            var readfoo = context.Foos.FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine($"{readfoo.Name} has the following children:");
            foreach(var child in readfoo.Children)
                Console.WriteLine(child.Name);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The results is as expected:

[image]

I hope I helped you solve your problem and understand a bit more the world of Entity Framework.

Comment: I implemented a similar version after the comments on my post, I did some research about how to implement a tree in a relational database. But some steps weren't as clear, but you summed it up pretty neatly and in a understandable way! Thanks a lot, marked as the solution, that was really helpful. Hoping that people who come across the same issue can find the solution here.